# Chaining querysets in managers

Tags: python, django

I am looking for a way to reuse this abstract model/manager with queryset on the models that require soft delete but some of my models already have custom managers/querysets. Ideally I would like all of those other managers to use `SoftDelete` manager/queryset so that they would always return only undeleted items. Is there a way to achieve this in Django 1.10?

```
class SoftDeleteQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        for obj in self:
            obj.is_active = False
            obj.save()

    def undelete(self):
        for obj in self:
            obj.is_active = True
            obj.save()

class SoftDeleteManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset():
        return SoftDeleteQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).filter(is_active=True)

class SoftDelete(Model):
    is_active = m.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = SoftDeleteManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def delete(self):
        self.is_active = False
        self.save()

    def undelete(self):
        self.is_active = True
        self.save()
```

Comment: You don't need chaining, you need inheritance.

Comment: I am guessing you are thinking about manager inheritance, right? I have tried manager inheritance but as I understand you still have to override `get_queryset` but I couldnt figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the parent class of your models from `Model` to `SoftDelete`:

```
class MyModel1(SoftDelete):
    # ...

    objects = MyModel1Manager()
```

and also for your managers:

```
class MyModel1Manager(SoftDeleteManager):
    # ...
```

also for inheritance on your get_queryset (as mentioned in the comments), you should use something like this:

```
class MyModel1Manager(SoftDeleteManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(...)
```

Comment: This is where it gets interesting. If you want to apply `MyModel1QuerySet` methods on the `super().get_queryset()` it has to be something different.

Comment: I think adding one more inheritance would solve the issue (`MyModel1QuerySet` should also inherit from `SoftDeleteQuerySet`). Basically your models, managers and querysets should inherit from the `SoftDelete`.